# confirm box jquery

Tags: jquery, confirm

I'm using  Predefined jquery css form Template.

```
<asp:Button ID="btndeleteselected" runat="server" Text="Delete" 
     CssClass="basicBtn mr10 ml10 bConfirm"  OnClick="btndeleteselected_Click"  />
```

When I click on button I need to dispaly confirm box to delete. But when I clicked on button

event is firing without getting confirm box . What do I need to do?

my jquery function is

```
$(".bConfirm").click( function() {
    jConfirm('Can you confirm this?', 'Confirmation Dialog', function(r) {
        jAlert('Confirmed: ' + r, 'Confirmation Results');
    });
});
```

It is defiend in custom.js predefined jquery files

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell the click event not to process, by calling `preventDefault()` on the event passed to the click handler:

```
$(".bConfirm").click( function(e) {
    jConfirm('Can you confirm this?', 'Confirmation Dialog', function(r) {
        jAlert('Confirmed: ' + r, 'Confirmation Results');
    });
    e.preventDefault();
    return false
});
```